# How to use Schema.org for an overview of product categories?

Tags: categories, schema.org

I'm doing the SEO for an e-commerce platform.
The product detail page is already optimized, but there's also an overview of product categories.

Here's a wireframe of the category page:

[image]

The images within the yellow box are products applied to the active category **cat 1**.

Do you have any suggestions or hints for the use of Schema.org on the category section (cat1 - cat4) page?

Answer (score 0):

I use [List](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/mark-up-listings) for category sites to enable a carousel of lists to appear in Search.